# c++ how to send const std::vector<std::uint8_t> over socket?

Tags: c++

I want to send `vector<uint8_t>` over socket but the **send()** func takes only **const char*** as a parameter.

my vector contains Pixels (over **4 million** element).

thank you in advance.

Comment: `send(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(v.data()))`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: VC++ v15 puts it this way: "error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'const char *' Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast".  Also http://ideone.com/tLC7W6

Comment: @TonyD Oops. Meant `reinterpret_cast<>`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: not a bad habit to try `static_cast<>` first anyway... :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast the vector's data to `const char*`:

```
reinterpret_cast<const char*>(my_vector.data())
```

Comment: thank you very much, but const char* max volum is under 60000 element. i have over 4 million element.

Comment: `const char*` just identifies the first character's memory address so doesn't itself have a "max volume", but TCP is a buffered byte-stream protocol so `send()` will typically only enqueue as many bytes as you can fit in the output buffer, alongside any other unsent data, and with blocking mode ensuring `send()` doesn't return until at least 1 extra byte's been enqueued.  The buffer size can vary with implementation.  Your application is expected to wait until the socket becomes writable again, then send more data.  You can test for writability with `select()`, or loop sending.